# When mounting a WIM file, does the performance of the disk containing the mountpoint matter?

Tags: windows, mount, dism, wim

Let's say I am mounting a WIM image on Windows using dism:

```
dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:D:\work\sources\install.wim /Index:1 /MountDir:E:\work.tmp
```

Here, `D:\work` is the "source" directory (containing extracted contents of a Windows installation disk) and `E:\work.tmp` is the scratch directory.

My intention is to carry out modifications (apply updates, integrate drivers, edit registry) to the image. I am interested in reducing the time it will take me to carry out those modifications (that is, speeding up I/O to the mounted image).

---

With respect to I/O performance to the mounted image, does it matter if `E:` is a slow disk or a fast disk? Why?

Comment: One question per Question, please.

Comment: @gronostaj The bonus question was mostly a "why" to the main one. But alright, I've dropped it.

Comment: Disk speed matters to reading/writing, especially for large data.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I know that "disk speed matters for reading/writing" in general, that's more or less obvious. The question, though, was whether disk speed _of the volume containing the WIM mountpoint_ matters. That is a completely different question.

Comment: Why do you think there will be a difference in speed?

Comment: @harrymc Because I noticed that when I mount a WIM image onto a mountpoint, the "free space" on the volume containing the mountpoint reduces exactly by the total size of all files in the WIM image. Maybe Windows implements "mounting a WIM" by transparently extracting the WIM contents into the mountpoint?

(This all was in the part of the question that I deleted by request above.)

Comment: I think you're looking at it wrongly : You have proven by your observation that the mount copies the data, which is logical, as export wouldn't be necessary if the modifications were done in-place. So the speeds of mount, modification and export are exactly those of the disk.

Comment: Perfectly valid question, I wish someone had an answer to this.
WIM handling in Windows is certainly suboptimal, e.g. unmounting a read-only mounted WIM image still takes minutes, which does not make sense.
Also, @harrymc, just observing the software's behavior does explain how it works internally: "used" space on the mount point might just as well be pre-allocated, and not actually used until the image is updated.